# WrapPanel in Expander won't decrease height

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a simple `materialDesign:Card` (which acts like a `Grid`) with an `Expander` as Content. The `Expander.Content` is set a `WrapPanel` with simple Components like `ComboBoxes`, so that them can wrap on resize (when expanded). Works like a charm expect that the `materialDesign:Card` wont stretch back until I collapse the `Expander` and expand it again.

So it looks like that:

[image]

And here is my XAML Code:

```
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <materialDesign:Card Grid.Row="0"
                                 Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                 AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                                                  Path=ActualHeight}"
                                 Margin="5"
                                 Background="White">
                <Expander Margin="10, 10, 10, 8"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                          materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth4"
                          IsExpanded="False">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0"
                                    Height="35"
                                    Margin="5, 0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                    Focusable="False"
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolButton}">
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Width="22"
                                                         Height="22"
                                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                         Foreground="Black"
                                                         Kind="Magnify" />
                            </Button>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                    AncestorType={x:Type Expander}},
                                                     Path=ActualWidth}"
                                     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Filmtitel"
                                     FontSize="16" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <WrapPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ComboBox Width="160"
                                  Height="40"
                                  Margin="20, 10, 0, 0"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding GenreAuswahl,
                                                        Converter={converter:EnumToCollectionConverter},
                                                        Mode=OneTime}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding GenreAuswahl}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Value" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100"
                                  Height="40"
                                  Margin="20, 10, 0, 0"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding FskAuswahl,
                                                        Converter={converter:EnumToCollectionConverter},
                                                        Mode=OneTime}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding FskAuswahl}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Value" />
                        <TextBox Width="200"
                                 MaxWidth="200"
                                 Margin="20, 10, 0, 0"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.Hint="Regisseuer" />
                        <materialDesign:RatingBar Margin="20, 10, 0, 0"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  Value="{Binding BewertungAuswahl}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Expander>
            </materialDesign:Card>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: cannot understand what do you want:). Could you clarify?

Comment: @StepUp The expanded search wraps when you decrease the window size and then the card gets bigger logically, but when you then increase the window size back, normally the search card should get smaller again but in my case it stays big till you hide/expand the Expander again. --> Compare the search card height of the first and last picture

Comment: it is still unclear. I've seen the uppest and bottom images and cannot see any differences between them:)

Comment: @StepUp What should be unclear? The Expander (Content) is in the first Image like 5cm high and in the last / bottom picture like 7-8cm high allthough it only needs 5cm like in the first one.

Comment: I cannot see any difference between images:)

Comment: @StepUp You can see that there is an Expander with a search icon and a TextBox with watermark "Filmtitel", right? This Expander has its content set to a WrapPanel with two ComboBoxes etc.inside. When you decrease the window width, the WrapPanel will wrap its content and the Height of the expander grows! When you know increase the width of the window back, the WrapPanel will unwrap its content and the Expander Height **SHOULD** shrink back. Now look at the first Windows Expander height and then on the last Windows Expander height.. THEY ARE DIFFERENT HEIGHTS. Look at the bottom margin!